# jquery подставить нужные значения

Tags: jquery

нужно значение `s td_art nomob` подставить в ссылку `href="/search/?find=     "`
(где стоит равенство)

Сама ссылка
`<a class="new_link" href="/search/?find=4681" alt="кнопка" title="кнопка"</a>`

откуда нужно брать значение `<td class="s td_art nomob">4681</td>`

тоесть 4681 нужно вставить в `/search/?find=`

```
if($('.subdiv-katalog-to .table_main').text()){

$('.mainmenubg a').hide();
$('.mainmenubg').prepend('<a class="new_link" href="/search/?find=4681" alt="цена" title="цены">цены</a> ');
```

}

Answer (score 3):

Судя по описанию http://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr-attributeName-function, можно сделать как-то так:

```
$(".new_link").attr("href", function( i, val ) {
    return val + $('.s.td_art.nomob').text();
//  return $(this).attr("href") + $('.s.td_art.nomob').text();
});
```

Однако если на странице есть много ссылок `new_link` и много ячеек `td` с таким классом, то такой фокус не пройдет и нужно отталкиваться уже от более четкой разметки

Comment: Спасибо да их много , буду отталкиваться уже от более четкой разметки

Comment: @gbrgbr значит можно поставить галочку на ответ?)

Comment: Нет)) Прошу помочь в моем случаи как будет? выкладываю свой код

Comment: @gbrgbr я не люблю когда вопросы меняют после ответа. сейчас тут нужен немного другой ответ. по сути тебе нужно взять текст с элемента и сконкатинировать со строкой

Comment: Извиняюсь, не сразу догадался выложить свой код, думал на примере пойму всё